# Why does the framerate for my canvas game rise when I drag the window?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making a simple HTML5 game and decided to enable the FPS counter in Chrome, and I noticed something odd.

When running the game normally I get around 24 FPS, but when I move the window using two fingers on my mac, enabling the bounce-back effect the frame rate shoots up to 50-70 FPS.

I've tried to find out why by using the Dev Tools in Chrome, but unfortunately I don't seem to be able to make sense of it.

I've posted pictures of the game with the FPS counter just below:
[image: Game with low FPS]
Low FPS

[image: Game with high FPS, by dragging the window]
High FPS

Comment: Sounds like the scroll event firing continuously... see http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Timeline with Frame mode](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/02/Profiling-Long-Paint-Times-with-DevTools-Continuous-Painting-Mode)?